# Auto delete files every one hour in ubuntu

Tags: automation, cron, ubuntu-16.04

I want to delete a files in every one hour,  form the path `/var/tmp/dev.log` and other temp files from `/var/tmp` folder,  I'm using  Ubuntu Server 16.04

I created a corn job setup

```
00 * * * *  rm -rf /var/tmp/*.*
```

but I'm not getting.

Comment: add he full path to `rm` command

Comment: @RomeoNinov tried didn't work

Comment: Have you check what you have in logs?

Comment: @RomeoNinov directly I checked in path itself

Comment: each cron execution will have created an email and send to the particular user with various information (output to /dev/stdout and /dev/stderr). What does this email say? you can access it with the command `mail`

Comment: @kvantour yes I want to trigger after task complete

Comment: @KishoreDR I do not believe you understood me. When cron triggered, it will have send you an email with more information why it did not run as you expect it. Just type `mail` and you should see some emails which are cron related with all the information you need to understand the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution for delete files every one-hour using `crontab`.

First, write the shell script.

```
root@admin:/home/ubuntu#vi delete_cache.sh
```

after creating the file add the below scripts in delete_cache.sh

```
rm -rf /var/tmp/*
```

then run a `crontab`.

```
root@admin:/home/ubuntu# crontab -e   
0 * * * * /bin/sh /home/ubuntu/delete_cache.sh
```

The 0 at the beginning means to run at the 0th minute. the script would run every hour. for more [see here](https://crontab.guru), you can create your own `cronjobs`